# Webbrowser control add style to tags already having style

Tags: html, css, vb6, webbrowser-control

In vb6 web browser control i am want to set style property for backgrpund color.I am doing it as shown below

```
If P.getAttribute("name") = "mybookmark" Then
    P.Style.cssText = "background-color:#FFFFEB"
End If
```

But if i do this then it overrides the style properties if any are there already. for example if a html tag with `<A name="mybookmark" style="font-size:12px">abc</A>` exists then my code will remove existing style add background color property. So how to add style property for existing one?

Comment: Long time since I did any of this but have you tried `P.Style.cssText = "background-color:#FFFFEB;"` & P.Style.cssText` ?

Comment: @Fred Worked fine!!..Please post it as answer so that i can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the existing style rather than replace it :)

`P.Style.cssText = "background-color:#FFFFEB;" & P.Style.cssText`

Comment: I think you might be better off using P.Style.cssText & "background-color:#FFFFEB;".  Basically, add the background color after the existing style instead of before it.  I don't know for sure but I think that if there is already a background color set for it, putting your background color before the existing style will not work, but putting it after will.

Comment: @GMastros That is how I first wrote it but then thought about the semi colon.  IE. Does the existing string have a semi colon on the end.  Instead of testing for it I added it to the beginning of the string.  However you do raise a valid point that would need testing.