# Get values of particular style properties by using web browser control

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb6, webbrowser-control

In my VB6 application, I am using the Web Browser control. I want to load an HTML page in the Web Browser control and get particular style properties. I previously posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811417/webbrowser-control-add-style-to-tags-already-having-style) about how to add styles. So how can I get text-indent property and left-margin properties of an HTML tag? In my case all styles are within the tag and I don't use external CSS.